# How to set-up php in order to insert data into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert some data into a database using an html form. The form is coded in html, the database is managed using MySQL and I'm using php to insert data. I think the problem is not on the code but in the php set-up (I include the code just in case).

I've installed MAMP (I'm working on a Snow Leopard Mac). PHP seems to be working properly (If I enter commands on the terminal everything works fine)

The action of the form is a php file called `insertar.php`

The problem is that when I click on the submit button after filling the form, the browser shows the code for `insertar.php` but it doesn't insert.

I would greatly appreciate your help.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$conn)
  {
  die('Imposible efectuar la conexion' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("zealot", $conn);

$id    = $_POST["id"];
$date  = $_POST["date"];
$name  = $_POST["name"];


mysql_query("insert into logistica_rastreo values('$id' , '$date' , '$name');");  


?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="the_form" method="post" action="insertar.php">
    <table>
    id:        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="40" name="id"/>                          
    date:      <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="40" name="date"/>           
    name:      <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="40" name="name"/>              
  </table>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="registrar" />
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: If your server shows code for `insertar.php` (which is type of PHP), than your server has not allowed PHP.

Comment: I run insertar.php removing every line that has `$_POST`and using a manual insert in `mysql_query` and it works!.  I think the php file is correct. [By the way, this is the first php script that I'm running in this computer]

Comment: Your server appears to be setup not to execute PHP, but it merely shows the PHP code. If you're using apache, are you sure mod_php is enabled?

Comment: @Konerak I´ve taken a look at the output of phpinfo and it says that mod_php5 is loaded. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: phpinfo works, but your other php code doesn't? So if you create file.php with contents `<? phpinfo(); ?>`, that executes? And `otherfile.php` with contents `<? die('test 123'); ?>` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi deps_stats,
          you HTML and PHP code is perfectly ok as far as i can verify this...

You need to check your server settings from cpanel, and check whether query modules (i.e execution, deletion,etc are enabled or not)..

This problem is at your server level not at code level... Hope this would help..

Comment: if you dont get, we could discuss overthis again... :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but it's good practice to always make sure to specify which columns you want to insert into. For example, instead of this:

```
mysql_query("insert into logistica_rastreo values('$id' , '$date' , '$name');");
```

do something like this:

```
mysql_query("insert into logistica_rastreo(id,date,name) values('$id' , '$date' , '$name');");
```